# What does "I'll kill that cat" in the play Dinner for One mean?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, popular-refrains, meaning

In the play [Dinner for One](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD8k1CnVeAQ), James the butler says, "I'll kill that cat," [at time 14:05](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD8k1CnVeAQ#t=14m05s). What does this mean? Is he referring to the tiger rug which keeps tripping him, or is it a saying or colloqualism?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about a storyline.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves textual analysis (as in the fine accepted answer) rather than basic English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinner_for_One), the "cat" reference is a consequence of drinking the water the flowers were standing in.  That is, James has approached Mr. Winterbottom's chair; by mistake he picks up the cup with flowers, pitches them away, and drinks the water.  The reference mentioned above comments:

> Schließlich zeigt er unzählige Varianten des Einschenkens und trinkt versehentlich aus der Blumenvase statt aus dem Becher, was er mit einem deutlichen Verziehen des Gesichts und der Bemerkung “I’ll kill that cat!” quittiert (sinngemäß: „das schmeckt wie Katzenurin“)

which (in effect) says that after numerous variants of mis-pourings, he drinks by mistake from the vase rather than the cup, then with significant facial distortion  exclaims, "I'll kill that cat!" – with implication, "this tastes like cat pee".

Answer (score 0):

After the line, he appears to fan fumes away from himself and away from his backside. This leads me to believe he has passed gas and is attempting to blame it on a cat (or in his drunkenness indeed believes it was a cat who broke wind), as in the more frequent trope of blaming it on a dog.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you know the language, and you just really look at what happens that leads up to him saying that (about 1000 times?), then it is OBVIOUS that it has noting to do with the tiger, but rather with the flower water tasting like cat urine... I would think because they do have a cat and it peed in the vase.
I get angry when paid commentators say that he is referring to the tiger.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything that's not in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -4):

Comes from a time when cats were less loved and kept more for practical purposes (catching mice) and were blamed or used as a scapegoat (Sündenbock) for any otherwise inexplicable minor bad surprise, the expression became common and was used even when there was no possibility that a cat could have been the cause.

Comment: I have never heard this before. Do you have any links that discuss this kind of story?